# History of the name "$PS1"?

Tags: linux, shell

Why is the variable containing the shell prompt called `PS1` ?
Where does it come from ?

Does there exist `PS2`, `PS3`, etc ... ?

Comment: PS2, PS3 and PS4 does exists, look [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/131510-need-explanation-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4.html)

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32096/why-is-bashs-prompt-variable-called-ps1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PS used in variable names PS*n* comes from the term 'Prompt Statement'.

**And yes,** PS2 & PS3 also exists along with PS4.

A very well written articles is available on this topic at: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/

-Relfor